# Is there any ways to check if any chars from a string are in another string without using loops

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to determine if any characters from a string1 are in another string2

```
example:
string1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

any of the characters from this string1 are in this string2 for example:

string2="HELLO WoRLD"
```

but i want to do so **without using any loops**, is there anything that can be done in python maybe using the **in** statement

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using sets

```
str1 = 'abcd'
str2 = 'bcde'

set1 = set(str1) 
set2 = set(str2)

if set1.intersection(set2):
    print('There are same chars in the strings')
```